# Eclipse Doesn't show JNA User Libs

Tags: java, eclipse

JNA is not showing the library paths when importing

Here is my problem in pictures:[com.sun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEiTZ.png)
[com.sun.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivZA6.png)

Essentially when I write com.sun. does it not show a list of classes/packages etc.

Sorry if I'm being stupid but I am new to relatively to java and eclipse.

Editing .classpath directly.
Readding Libraries.
Looked through project properties but can't find anything related.

Comment: Oracle purchased Sun in 2010; why would you expect anything from Sun in the modern JVM?

Comment: Sorry, I think I've wrote this horribly, JNA is not showing the packages. So from the github what I understand is you import it like this: import com.sun.jna

Comment: [**Moved** / **Renamed**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna)

Comment: Find it on `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna/5.13.0`, you can download the jar file (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/5.13.0/jna-5.13.0.jar) , `import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;

public class Main {`. It can work with JDK 17.

Comment: "Sorry if I'm being stupid but I am new to relatively to java and eclipse." - please don't write such a thing, it's not relevant to the question and will be considered noise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your [Type Filters](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/appearance/ref-preferences-type-filters.htm). You usually don't want to directly reference com.sun packages, so they're likely in the default set of packages not offered through Content Assist and in other functionality.